# Access SMS in Android and send to default IP

Tags: android, sms

I am making an application which after installation will block the message from sending to receiver, intercept in between and send the message to an IP for filter.

User will not see any pop up or any thing, user will make SMS in the normal way, but at the time of click of send button the text message will go to the pre mentioned IP address.

Is there any way to intercept the sent SMS in between and push it to an IP server.

Can any one help in this.

Comment: Believe me if you are able to code such app it will would be pulled back by Google

Comment: Actually I am not making it for market, I need it because of my own need... Can you help?

Comment: @ingsaurabh why do you say so?

Comment: I dont think it is possible unless the user makes the app that you building the default app to handle sms

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible. You can't "hack" the pre-installed or other SMS applications.
The only thing you can do is to write your own sms app which sends the text to your ip server.